# "exceeded the maximum file size" error even when uploading small files

Tags: 7, files

This error in my Drupal 7 site happens when I try to upload an image through `image_field` field. This is the error:

> An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded
>   the maximum file size (64 MB) that this server supports.

[image]

Although I am trying to upload a small 5KB photo, this problem exists. I know this is kind of common problem, but can't understand why this happens for as small images as 5KB!

How I can fix this? At first I thought this issue may have been temporary and does appear to have resolved itself this morning but again it happens.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with server config - try installing a blank version of Drupal on the same server and see if you have the same problem. If so, you know it's the server; if not, you know it's something wrong with the config on the first site

Comment: thats a good idea, is there any problem if i install a fresh d7 with the same database and username ? Thanks

Comment: I know this question is pretty old, but did you manage to fix the issue ? if so could you please give me an idea about it?

Comment: I was on a shared host then, and it was a server issue! i contacted the web host provider and they fixed the issue

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround, as this is a tricky one to nail down.

Don't hit the "Upload" button at all.  Just hit the "Next" button directly.  If that works, you ran into the same problem I did.

Comment: That may be an okay workaround but it doesn't solve the underlying problem so you will likely run into related issues at some stage in future.